# How do I read from a pointer that looks like "process name" + address?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, pointers

As the title says I'm trying to read from an address I found in Cheat Engine's pointer scan. But the only problem is the only pointers I've ever had to work with are just Pointer Address + Offset. I am using C# .Net 4.0 from Visual Studio 2010. I think I remember seeing something about this before but I didn't think to much about it as it didn't apply to me at the time.

Something about getting the Process or Module ID and adding it to the pointer address then adding the offset and reading from there? But I can't remember the commands to get a processes ID or Module ID :/

Also this is a level 5 pointer I'm working with, I've only used level 1 or 2 pointers but I'm guessing it's around the same. Just read the address from the pointers until I get a base address to write to.

If it helps my pointer looks like this:
"ProcessName.exe"+003E6D98

"It might help if you said why in the world you need to play with pointers from .NET" - John Saunders

I am making a trainer for one of my games. I've made them before just not with this type of pointer and I forgot exactly how to handle this type of address. I think I have to get the module's id but I've forgotten how. I'm actually pretty good with memory and pointers I just usually have the average address without the process name next to it.

Comment: OpenProcess plus ReadProcessMemory

Comment: It might help if you said why in the world you need to play with pointers from .NET

Comment: You can create a reference to the Process by looking for process name by looping through the running programs.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I am going to guess its because he is familar with C# and unfamilar with C++ and there is nothing wrong with dealing with pointers in .NET if you understand what your doing.  I would even argue its even easier because IF you do something wrong you quickly are informed your doing something wrong instead of being allowed to do something that is wrong.

Comment: @Ramhound: the reason I asked the OP is because I didn't want to guess.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - His reasons for using C# is not important.  He wants a solution in C# if you have the ability to guide him you should do so.  My knowlege is limited to the Process class.

Comment: @Ramhound: did you notice that I asked him why he's using pointers in .NET, not why he's using C#? Are you his friend or something and need to defend him? Let the OP answer.

Comment: Ah, didn't see this comment box.. Ended up adding to the original post instead. Don't worry I know what i'm doing in C# and memory stuff i'm just new to making a program to do it. I've already made some memory programs but i've never had to use a process that needs process name + address and so i'm asking for help.

Oh and you are correct. I've only programmed in VB.Net/6, C#, and a bit in ASM i've never touched C++ though I plan to.

Comment: A "level 5" pointer? What is that?

Answer (score 0):

**OP answered in question - put as CW answer**

```
string sProcessName = "MyProcessName.exe";
Process[] MyProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(sProcessName);
IntPtr hProcModuleBA = MyProcesses[0].MainModule.BaseAddress;
IntPtr PointerAddr = new IntPtr(MyPointer.ToInt32() + BaseAddress.ToInt32());
```

This will search through your processes for sProcessName, add it to an array 'MyProcesses'. I chose the first one in the list to get the BaseAddress from. It was 40000 :)